# How to remove last element from a List<String>

Tags: apex

I have a requirement to exclude last element from a list.
For example if my list is like this:

```
List<String> str=new List<String>{'2023, 2024, 2025, 2026, 2027'};
```

I need a new list which will have only  till 2026.

If I have a list :

```
List<String> = new List<String>{'2023, 2024'};
```

I need a new list which will have only 2023.

I created a new `List<string> str1 = new List<string>();`

I tried to use the traditional for loop but it seems to be not working.

```
for(Integer i=0; i< (str.size()-1); i++){
   str1.add(str(i));
}
```

Error:
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void str(Integer) from the type myApexClass

Any way to add the desired output to the new List str1, please suggest.

Comment: Again, please take more care to ensure that your example code is syntactically correct and that it's a faithful reproduction of what you actually have. `List<String> str= '2023, 2024, 2025, 2026, 2027';` is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`.remove(index)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_System_List_remove) to remove the last element from a list. The index of the last element is always `size() - 1`.

```java
List<String> years = new List<String>{ '2023', '2024', '2025', '2026', '2027' };
years.remove(years.size() -1 );
System.debug(years); // Print (2023, 2024, 2025, 2026)
```

Please note that `.remove(index)` returns the elment being removed, so writing `years = years.remove(years.size() -1 );` would result in the following error:

> Illegal assignment from String to List

Once you call `.remove(index)` the size of the list changes.

The for-loop idea is fine, but you should use [`.get(index`)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_System_List_get) or the square bracket notation to get the element of index `i`, that's why you got

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void str(Integer)

```java
List<String> years = new List<String>{ '2023', '2024', '2025', '2026', '2027' };
List<String> years2 = new List<String>();
Integer lastElementIndex = years.size() - 1;
for(Integer i=0; i<lastElementIndex; i++){
   years2.add(years.get(i)); // or years2.add(years[i]);
}
System.debug(years2);
```

Comment: Hi @rubenDG, I tried to use remove() but I'm getting this error: Illegal assignment from String to List<String>

Comment: Here is how i'm trying to use it:
 List<String> allYearsList = new List<String>{ '2023', '2024', '2025', '2026', '2027' };
allYearsList = allYearsList.remove(allYearsList.size() -1 );

It is giving me error:  Illegal assignment from String to List<String>

Comment: @sfdcDev  `remove(index)` returns the element that has been removed from the list, that's why you got that error. You don't need to reassing the result to `allYearsList`. Please change `allYearsList = allYearsList.remove(allYearsList.size() -1 );` to `allYearsList.remove(allYearsList.size() -1 );`. By the way, you could try my snippet in the developer console

Comment: I did try the other way suggested by you:
Integer lastElementIndex = years.size() - 1;

This is working as expected for me, Thanks for your time and effort on this @RubenDG